# Missing Temporal in Properties

Tags: qgis

I am trying to follow the tutorial here [A GPX file (second example)](https://courses.spatialthoughts.com/spatial-data-viz.html#introduction)[image: Screen grab of Properties dialogue.] but "Temporal" is missing from the properties dialogue box.  I deleted Maderia and loaded Coruna in case that was the problem but "Temporal" is still missing from properties.  I also un-installed Time Manager but no difference.  Is there something that needs to be done to activate this property?